# How to check the internet connectivity in xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing iOS app, that fully needs internet connectivity to run. So every time it needs to check the internet connectivity of the device. Kindly help me to solve this problem with some simple solution. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please do some research before asking such a common question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3597085/3411191

Comment: @rmaddy I surf a lot but I can't find any simple solution thats why I asked. And I am very new to iOS.

Comment: Here's a tip when working with distributed and or networked systems - just because a service is reachable when you check, doesn't mean it will still be reachable when you're actually using it.

Comment: @rmaddy I am using xcode 4.5 but the sample code is for xcode 5 and above. Kindly give some suggestions. Thank you..

Comment: Use Xcode 5. You have to if you plan to send your app to Apple.

Comment: @rmaddy If I develop this app in Xcode 4.5 means Apple Doesn't accept my app?

Comment: That is correct. You must use Xcode 5, you must fully support iOS 7, and you must fully support 4" screens, and you must fully support retina displays. Failure to do any of these and Apple won't accept your app.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's Reachability will help you do that.

> The Reachability sample application demonstrates how to use the
>   SystemConfiguration framework to monitor the network state of an iOS
>   device. In particular, it demonstrates how to know when IP can be
>   routed and when traffic will be routed through a Wireless Wide Area
>   Network (WWAN) interface such as EDGE or 3G.

https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: How did you submit this after I closed the question? Strange.

Comment: We probably both submitted at the same time :)

Comment: I closed the question 15 seconds before you posted your answer. Must be a bug. BTW - I didn't down vote you.

Comment: It [happens occasionally](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252711/this-answer-was-posted-after-the-question-was-closed-how-is-that-possible?lq=1), @rmaddy; it's more of a networking issue than a flat-out bug.